# Какие есть подходы к организации модулей?

Tags: архитектура, любой-язык, модульность

Мне интересно узнать какие есть подходы к организации модулей для программ. Интересуют вообще способы разбиения программ на части и связывание этих частей.

Если отошлёте к какому-нибудь эзотерическому языку, в котором используется оригинальный подход -- буду только рад.

Перечислю что уже мне известно, дабы не утруждать отвечающих:

- Прямое включения в глобальное пространство имён. Когда все символы (имена функций классов) включаются как есть, что сильно замусоривает пространство имён.
  **Языки**: C, C++ (правда `namespace`s частично спасают), PHP, Ruby (`Module`s тоже спасают), Scheme
- Импорт как модуля, возможность явно указать имя для включенного модуля (что-то вроде alias) и обращаться к символам по этому имени. Глобальное пространство имён не замусоривается.
  **Языки**: Java, Python, Haskell, D

Кроме того в некоторых языках можно указывать имя подключаемого модуля в рантайме, в других нет.

Собственно вопрос: есть ли какие-либо языки или подходы которые не попадают ни в одну из описанных выше категорий? Есть ли языки где даже эти подходы реализованы нестандартно?

Comment: Подозреваю это будет ещё один заумный вопрос без ответов.

Comment: Время покажет. :)

Comment: Сюда же отнес бы и ассемблеры, типо tasm, masm, nasm .

Не понял ответа<<< Вас интересует экзотические подходы к разбиению кода по файлам, т.е. модульность и обращение к этим модулям.
Я привел примеры языков где такое как раз есть. Загуглите, думаю найдете много интересного

Comment: Нет, не разбиение по файлам, а модульность. Способ организовать большое количество кода (возможно написанного разными людьми), да так, чтобы не было конфликтов, можно было учесть различные версии библиотек.

Comment: хаххахахаха, т.е. модульность не подразумевает под собой разбиение на файлы? В большинстве ООП языков это так. Ваш вопрос расходиться с этим комментарием, В вопросе вас интересует вообще разные организации разбиения, а тут вы хотите увидеть самую лучшую.
Ничего совершенного нет.

Comment: Разбиение на файлы -- необязательно. Есть языки где можно создать несколько модулей в одном файле и наоборот, растянуть определение модуля на несколько файлов.

Comment: Меня интересует то что я указал в вопросе.

Comment: <i>Когда все символы (имена функций классов) включаются как есть, что сильно замусоривает пространство имён.</i>
Для С++ это некорректно, т.к. область видимости ф-ции класса - этот класс. Т.е. напрямую эта ф-ция не замусоривает глобальное пространство имен. Для С - корректно, т.к. там нет классов, namespace'ов и пр., а ф-ции доступны везде, где есть их определения.

Comment: @Vladimir Gordeev, не знаю, насколько информация будет интересна (и в тему), но "краем глаза" видел (детально не вникал) - в ядре linux есть динамически загружаемые модули. 

Что интересно, модулю доступны не все, а лишь специально проэкспортированные глобальные имена как из основной (статически собранной) части ядра, так и из других динамических модулей (от которых зависит загружаемый).

Да и вообще, связывание с  .so (или .dll) в ответах не было затронуто.

Comment: @avp, мне кажется, модули ядра - это из другой оперы. К языковым средствам они не имеют никакого отношения. Динамическое связывание библиотек - то же самое. Это скорее технология как таковая, а не языковое средство. На низком уровне, как я понимаю, языковое средство под название "модуль" часто реализуется как интерпретатором или виртуальной машиной как раз через динамическое связывание.

Comment: @mikillskegg, мне тоже кажется, что ТС интересуется именно языковыми аспектами модульности, но на всякий случай (возмодно из-за причины закрытия вопроса) решил кинуть информацию.

Answer (score 2):

> Языки: C, C++ (правда namespaces частично спасают),

Более занятно другое: в C/C++ пространство доступных идентификаторов ограничивается исходным файлом, в котором имя определено. Соответственно, чтобы иметь возможность подцепить функцию, переменную из другого файла приходится выкручиваться с помощью h-ников. Это для этапа компиляции. А вот на линковке можно получить ошибку о дублирующихся идентификаторах.
Итого, что имеем для C:

1. чтобы подцепить идентификатор из другого модуля - требуется явное определение в файле, где он используется.
2. чтобы идентификатор был доступен СТРОГО из одного модуля без возможности использования в других - есть ключевое слово static. В противном случае, как писал выше - ошибка линкера.

Comment: Спасибо, про такое поведение static не знал.

Answer (score 0):

Python - язык основаный на модулях которых предостаточно для любой задачи. Используеться простой импорт модуля и обращение к нему по имени.

Comment: Это ответ не на тот вопрос. А насчёт любой задачи вы преувеличиваете.

Comment: Ну для почти любой. Пока ещё не встретил задачь с которыми не возможно было справиться на этом языке.

Comment: Это значит, что просто задачи вы рассматривали очень определённые.